# how to access spring beans from objects not created by spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my web application i use hibernate and spring. Entity classes that are returned from Hibernate layer need to access other service classes in some scenarios. Entity classes are not just DTO's they contains some business logic, and to perform some business logic (like may be send out emails etc when some conditions are met) these need to access service classes. Service classes are spring beans. so what's the recommended method in such scenarios to get hold of spring beans from within these entity classes which are created outside spring context?

Comment: Personally, I would not like having my DTO's *access* my service classes, but rather *provide* them to the service classes as a part of the workflow of retrieving Entities from Hibernate.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild these are meant to be rich domain objects and therefore need to carry business logic.

Comment: I've worked on this app https://danjee.github.io/hedgehog/ Maybe it will be helpful in the future

Answer (score 20):

You are looking for [Service-locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) pattern,

Implementation in Spring

You can register `ApplicationContextAware` and get reference to `ApplicationContext` and statically serve bean

```
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {
 private static ApplicationContext ctx;

 private static final String USER_SERVICE = "userServiceBean";

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext)
      throws BeansException {
    ctx = appContext;

  }

  public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return ctx;
  }

  public static UserService getUserService(){return ctx.getBean(USER_SERVICE);}

}
```

Comment: But this implementation can give major error in Sonar(code conversion tool) because we are setting static field from non static method. So to avoid that you may have to create separate AppContext class where you initialize application context through static getApplicationContext() method and set context using static setApplicationContext(). Call this set method of AppContext from class implementing ApplicationContextAware like below  `@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) { AppContext.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
}`

Comment: another option could be to do it in the startup class:
`public static ApplicationContext context` and then in the main: `context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)`. Then you can get a bean from everywhere using `Application.context.getBean(XYZ.class)` or similar

Answer (score 6):

Read about `@Configurable` annotation that allows to configure beans using AspectJ:

- [Spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)
- [Spring blogs](http://spring.io/blog/2008/01/24/new-improvements-in-domain-object-dependency-injection-feature)

If you don't want to use AspectJ, you could use the

`ApplicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean()`

method to configure beans that live outside the spring container. (see java docs).

Comment: does AspectJ work with final classes and classes that are serialized to the DB and stored as BLOB?

Comment: I'm getting error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAutowireCapableBeanFactory() from the type AbstractApplicationContext